# Show that $\sum a_nx^n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

The problem is: Suppose the convergence radius of the power series $\sum a_n x^n$ is equal to $1$, also the coefficients of the series satisfy $a_1\geq a_2\geq a_3\geq ...$ and $a_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$. Show that $\sum a_n x^n$ converges for all $x$ such that $|x|=1$, except maybe at $x=1$.

**My attempt:** Let $b_n=a_nx^n$, if we take $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg\vert\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\bigg\vert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg\vert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg\vert\vert x\vert=0$$ if $|x|\leq 1$, then, by the ratio test, the serie $\sum a_nx^n$ converges for all $|x|=1$. Observe that, the series $\sum\frac{x^n}{n}$ when $x=1$ is the harmonic series, and does not converge, but when $x=-1$ it does, then the series does not necessarily converge when $x=1$.

I know that my attempt is wrong since I don't use the fact that the convergence radius is 1 or that $a_n\to 0$, but I don't have any ideas on how to fix it or do it.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why would $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n+1}/a_n|=0$?

Comment: "powers serie" -> "power series" (series is always plural)

Comment: Do we allow $x$ to be complex?  So $|x| = 1$ is not just two points, but a whole circle?  This version of your result is still true.

Answer (score 2):

This question is tagged [real-analysis](/questions/tagged/real-analysis), so I assume by $|x|=1$ you mean $x\in\{-1,1\}$. The convergence for $x=-1$ is given by [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Dirichlet%27s_test) which says
$\require{cancel}$

> If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence of $\overset{\large\text{real}}{\cancel{\text{complex}}}$ numbers satisfying
>
> - $a_n\ge a_{n+1}$
> - $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$
> - $\displaystyle\left|\ \sum_{n=1}^Nb_n\ \right|\le M$ for every positive integer $N$
>
> where $M$ is some constant, then the series
>
> $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$
>
> converges.

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^{n-1}\in\{0,1\}$, Dirichlet's Test applies.

Comment: Yeah, just it. Dirichlet's theorem is enough for this question and the results stay true even if we extend $x$ to be in the complex plane.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen: Indeed. Just remove the canceling I did and modify the last sum to $$\left|\,\sum_{n=1}^Nx^{n-1}\,\right|=\left|\,\frac{1-x^N}{1-x}\,\right|\le\frac2{|1-x|}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question real analysis, I'll assume you are concerned with $x \in [-1,1]$.

As you mentioned, the harmonic series is the counterexample for $x=1$.

For $|x|<1$ note that:

$$
|a_n x^n| \leq |x|^n \text{ and that } \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x|^n < \infty
$$ since the latter is a geometric sum with rate $|x|$.

For the case $x=-1$, this is the alternating harmonic series and is often an example of a series which is convergent but not absolutely convergent.